# abort Link redirection in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, hyperlink

Hi Guys i have a small problem,

i have a click event on a settings icon but the settings icon is inside a link so when i click the icon the click event is called but i cant see anything because i getting redirected to the next page so i need a way to click the icon without firing the link

```
<template name="startseite">
    <div id="viewport">
        {{#each gebiet}}
        <div id="viewmode">
    this is the link--> <a id="link" href="/straßen/{{this._id}}">
                <div id="gebietsCard">
                    <ul id="gebieteListe">
      and here the icon -->  <li id="settings"><i id="setting" class="material-icons md-24 md-light">settings</i></li>
                        <li id="überschrift">{{Gebietsname}}</li>
                        <li>{{Gebietsnummer}}</li>
                        <li>{{Ort}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="editmode">
            <div id="gebietsCardEdit">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

my js:

```
    Template.startseite.events({
          'click #settings': function(){
              console.log("geklickt")
            $("#editmode").css('display', 'inline');
            $("#viewmode").css('display', 'none');
    }    
});
```

I hope you can help me thanks Guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done easily with:

```
Template.startseite.events({
  'click #settings': function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // I am not sure if this is needed, try it yourself and remove if it is no use

    $("#editmode").css('display', 'inline');
    $("#viewmode").css('display', 'none');
  }
}
```

You can find more information regarding these two functions here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: perfect it works but if you want to use it with meteor you have to write event and not just e.

Comment: hmm? `e` is just a variable name you can name it whatever you like

Comment: e is actually an instance of 'event' object.